# Adding JButton by loop causes last Button to be oversized

Tags: java, loops, button

When I create a button using a loop, the last button has the size of the whole frame. How can I fix this?

```
package test;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class test{

private JFrame frame;
private static JButton[][] buttons  = new JButton[4][4];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                test window = new test();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public test() {
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(200, 200, 600, 600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    for(int i=0; i < 4; i++){
        for(int j=0; j < 4; j++){
            JButton btn = new JButton("" + i+j);
            btn.setBounds(60*i,60*j,60,60);
            if((i+j)%2==1)
            btn.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            buttons[i][j]  = btn;
            frame.add(btn);
        }
    }

}
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use setBounds(...) on the buttons. It is the job of the layout manager to determine the size/location of a component. The default layout manager for a JFrame is a BorderLayout. Only a single component can be added to the CENTER of the BorderLayout, so only the size/location of the last button added is being managed by the BorderLayout and the other buttons are ignored.
2. Use a different layout manager. I suspect you should be using the GridLayout. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples.
3. Don't use setBounds on the frame either. After you add the buttons to the frame and before you invoke setVisible(..) you should use frame.pack() so the buttons will be displayed at their preferred size.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good use for the Grid Bag Layout manager. Try something like this:

First, you need to import the GridBagConstraints class.

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
```

And then just make these changes to your for loops.

```
for(int i=0; i < 4; i++){
    for(int j=0; j < 4; j++){
        JButton btn = new JButton("" + i+j);
        //btn.setBounds(60*i,60*j,60,60);
        if((i+j)%2==1)
        btn.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        buttons[i][j]  = btn;
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = i;
        gbc.gridy = j;
        frame.add(btn, gbc);
    }
}
```

The Grid Bag Layout manager is pretty tricky, but once you understand how it works, it's really useful. You can check out [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) on Oracle for more information.

Hope that helps.